# Deleting record from state store using flink sql

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I have a flink sql streaming job, which is started from a query like this

```
INSERT INTO sink_table 
    SELECT r.field1,
           r. tenant_id,
           r.field2,
           r.field3,
           d.field4
    from table_1 r
             LEFT JOIN table_2 d
                       ON r.tenant_id = d.tenant_id AND r.field1 = d.field1
```

From what I understand, flink will have a state for `table_1` keyed by `tenant_id` and another state for `table_2` keyed by `tenant_id`.

Now I want to be able to delete all data from this state for a particular `tenant_id`. Currently i get an kafka event from a topic that says `tenant_id` needs to be deleted.
How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

As outlined on https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/concepts/dynamic_tables/, Flink has the concept of Dynamic Tables. Dynamic tables are foremost a logical concept. Dynamic tables are not necessarily (fully) materialized during query execution.

The result of this query is a changelog stream, meaning that the results that are being inserted into `sink_table` can also be deleted. If you want to delete the results for a specific tenant, there should be an incoming event where the result of your query would result in the deletion of the data for that tenant.

Comment: in coming event will be be at the `tenant_id` level. Where the data in the state will be at each item level for a tenant_id. 
Will be a single event i.e a `tenant_id` delete be enough to delete the state ?